# Split one column with mixed data into dataframe with 2 columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have around 80 .txt files that contain only 1 column originally, but the one column has two parameters that I need to concatenate and split.

Something like this:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell N |
| -------- |
| Column B |
| -------- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell N |

I need to aggregate column A in one dataset (or .txt file) and I can remove the data from column B.
How do I do that when I only have strings to do so?
I tried to merge the files into one, the problem is that column A data and column B still got one above the other.

I tried this:

```
path_dir = '/content/'
for files in os.listdir(path_dir):
  if files.endswith(".txt"):
  print(files)

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for files in os.listdir(path_dir):
  if files.endswith(".txt"):
    DataFrame = pd.read_csv(path_dir + files)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, DataFrame], ignore_index = True)
```

The code is working fine, but the problem is that the columns stay merged into one, like Column A / Column B / Column A / Column B, and so on.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you, please, add the code? Minimal code sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JuliaMeshcheryakova just added, thank you for the tips

Comment: Please, see an updated answer below.

Comment: Didn't get the question. Could you, please, create a sample constructor? To copy-paste. A combination of split and merge should work in any case with implementation details depending on what you know about the data. It also makes sense to comment the answer, not a question if you regret to answer - easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to merge several files into one dataset you usually need one of pandas methods: please, refer to [merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) article.

So steps are:

1. Read the data and create 2 Dataframes each having 1 column (that's what you already have).
2. Concat them with axis param specified.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 'ColumnB', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['ColumnA'])

second_column_index = df.index[df['ColumnA'] == 'ColumnB'].tolist()[0]

df1 = df.iloc[:second_column_index, :].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.iloc[second_column_index+1:, :].rename(columns={'ColumnA': 'ColumnB'}).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```